# Promises - error callback vs. catch

Tags: angularjs, q, angular-promise

Can somebody tell me if there is a difference between using an error callback vs. a `catch` function, when using `$q.promise` please?

E.g. are the two snippets of code functionally equivalent?

```
function doSomething0() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    ...

    return deferred.promise;
 }

 doSomething0()
    .then(doSomething1)
    .then(doSomething2)
    .then(doSomething3)
    .catch(function (err) {
        // do something with `err`
    });
```

vs.

```
function doSomething0() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    ...

    return deferred.promise;
 }

 function errorHandler(err) {
    // do something with `err`
 }

 doSomething0()
    .then(doSomething1, errorHandler)
    .then(doSomething2, errorHandler)
    .then(doSomething3, errorHandler);
```

If so, why use the second one? It looks far uglier and leads to more code duplication in my opinion?

Comment: The second version allows you to bring the promise back into a resolved state to continue with the chain anyway by returning anything other than an error or a rejected promise.

Comment: And if the error handler throws or returns a rejected promise, it will be called three times.

Comment: I think `errorHandler` will be called three times only if `doSomething3` fails. But if `doSomething2` fails, it will be called two times and if `doSomething1` fails, it will be called once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both will achieve the same thing, except the second one might run `errorHandler` three times (instead of just once). You are correct that it brings some code duplication, but it also allows you to treat whatever error happened and continue with your chain:

```
function errorHandler(err) {
  //log error, continue
  return $q.resolve('default value or something');
}

doSomething0()
  .then(doSomething1, errorHandler)
  .then(doSomething2, errorHandler)
  .then(doSomething3, errorHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I continue with the chain out of interest? Or will it just continue with the chain?

Comment: @keldar you just have to return a new `Promise` from your error handler function, just like in the example above!

Comment: No need to return a promise. You can simply return a value.

Comment: _"Both will achieve the same thing"_. **Not exactly.** See this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130000/5259296

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at the first sample:

```
doSomething0()
    .then(doSomething1, errorHandler)
    .then(doSomething2, errorHandler)
    .then(doSomething3, errorHandler);


// I've represented functions invocations as if they were synchronous to simplify the example to focus on the error handling
// The above sample is in a way "equivalent" to
try {
    // doSomething0()
    try {
        // doSomething1()
        try {
          // doSomething2()
        } catch(e0) {
           // handle error
        }  
    } catch(e1) {
         // handle error
    }
} catch(e2) {
     // handle error
}
// doSomething3()
```

But if an exception happens in the `doSomething3` handler, it won't be handled.

Ok, let's have a look at the second sample:

```
doSomething0()
    .then(doSomething1)
    .then(doSomething2)
    .then(doSomething3)
    .catch(function (err) {
        // do something with `err`
    });


// I've represented functions invocations as if they were synchronous to simplify the example to focus on the error handling
// The above sample is in a way "equivalent" to
try {
    // doSomething0()
    // doSomething1()
    // doSomething2()
    // doSomething3()
}
catch(e) {
    // Catch 'em all
    console.log(e)
}
```